# Assert that JSON response string matches a certain class with Spring WebMvcTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

Given a simple REST controller in Spring Boot...

```java
@GetMapping("/user/{email}")
public UserResponse getUser(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
    return userService.getUserByEmail(email);
}
```

... I created a `@WebMvcTest` using `MockMvc` to assert the JSON content of the `UserResponse` object. Is it possible to also assert that the JSON string matches the `UserResponse` class itself (similar to Java's `instance of`)? I found the following but this does not work:

`.andExpect(jsonPath("$", typeCompatibleWith(UserREsponse.class)))`

Comment: Hm. Why shouldn't it match the class? You are defining your controller method to return this class, the class is serialized to JSON. Why would it return something else in the test? You would be testing the framework, not your application (and I am very confident that the Spring developers already test their framework)

Comment: I agree. The idea behind my question was: We're using a `ResponseEnvelope` which defines some response metadata and a `payload` containing the actual data. In the controller tests, however, I don't want to assert the metadata in each test but only the `payload`. So I thought: "Hey, if this JSON represents a `ResponseEnvelope`, then I'm fine and concentrate on testing the payload".